# Git - "nothing added to commit but untracked files present" after listing every file in root

Tags: git, github

I am attempting to commit some files to Github, to a GitHub Pages branch. In response, it stated "Nothing added to commit but untracked files present" after listing out *every folder in my root directory*. My project is inside of a folder inside of my Documents folder. Does anyone understand why this might be happening?

```
    On branch gh-pages
Untracked files:
    ../../.atom/
    ../../.bash_history
    ../../.gimp-2.8/
    ../../.gitconfig
    ../../.gradle/
    ../../.idlerc/
    ../../.jssc/
    ../../.mongorc.js
    ../../.node_repl_history
    ../../.oracle_jre_usage/
    ../../.ssh/
    ../../.thumbnails/
    ../../.vim/
    ../../.viminfo
    ../../AppData/
    ../../Contacts/
    ../../Desktop/
    ../Thumbs.db
    ../desktop.ini
    ../forge.aup
    ../hp.system.package.metadata/
    ../../Downloads/
    ../../Dropbox/
    ../../Favorites/
    ../../Helper/
    ../../IntelGraphicsProfiles/
    ../../Links/
    ../../MongoDB/
    ../../Music/
    ../../OneDrive/
    ../../Pictures/
    ../../Saved Games/
    ../../Searches/
    ../../Videos/
    nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

Comment: Can you show us the complete error message and try to explain your setup?

Comment: Git is only telling you that there are untracked _files_ inside those _directories_, and also, in those same directories, there's not a single file that is already being tracked.

Comment: My best guess is that, by mistake (for example an accidental drag & drop in Windows Explorer) you moved the `.git` directory two levels up.

Comment: So where should the .git directory be? I only remember it ever being in my root directory.

Comment: It should be at the root *of the repo's default work tree* (probably your project directory), not the root of the filesystem.  How else would you ever have more than one repo cloned at the same time?

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

It seems most people are missing the crux of the issue here, so I'll add a bit:

You want to know why it's listing things outside your project directory as untracked.  As axiac observed, this most likely means that the .git folder is in the wrong place.  The .git folder contains all the metadata and repo-specific configuration, as well as the state of the index and the database (which in turn contains the version history, etc.)

When you're in a given working directory and you run a git command (if it's one that expects you to be in a repo... which is most of them), it looks for a .git folder in that directory; then if it doesn't find one it checks the parent directory, and so on until it either finds one or reaches the filesystem root.  If it doesn't find one it gives an error, but if it does find one, then it takes that to be the root of the default work tree for the repository.  (There are some cases where this description isn't applicable, but it should apply to your situation.)

So probably `.git/` is in the wrong place.  But that raises another question:  Why doesn't git think that you've deleted everything it already knew about?

Of course if this is a new repo that you're just creating, that would explain it; but if it's anything else, git should be listing deletion of any files from the previous commit as also being untracked changes.  (At least, it should if you do a `git status`.

So what to do next:

If you're creating a new repo, it may be best to delete `.git/` from your filesystem root, `cd` to your project directory and rerun `git init`

If this is an existing repo, try running `git status` to confirm that it sees untracked deletions of everything along with all your top-level files/folders as untracked files.  If so, you surely need to move the `.git/` that's in your filesystem root to the project directory.

Then you should be able to stage and commit your changes as usual.

Answer (score 0):

The "nothing added to commit" message refers to empty directories that have been added. GIT manages versions of files, not directories. When you git add a file in one of those directories, you will see them listed as "new file: ...".
The "untracked files present" refers to "../Thumbs.db", for which git add has not yet been run. Files are not "tracked" by GIT unless they have been "add"-ed to the index that GIT maintains.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to commit all the files, try the below commands

```
git add ../../.

git commit -m "commit message"
```

As per your question, you might be in two level sub directory of the repo path and executing git commands

It's good to initialise the project repository, so remove .git folder from root directory and change the directory to project path and initialise git repo by `git init` , Thanks @MarkAdelsberger

Comment: Advising OP on how to commit his entire filesystem, when he's stated that he is working in a project directory, is probably not the right thing to do.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger that's correct better to remove the .git folder on root directory and initialise git repo at project path

Comment: This answer is extremely misleading and dangerous !! Never force push stuff into your remote repo and pollute it,